# How to add different inputs values into array of objects dynamically in angualrJs

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple input fields under different headings:-

```
<label>User</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.username"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.userdob"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.userpanNo"/>

<label>Employee</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.empname"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.empdob"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.emppanNo"/>

<label>Daily Workers</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.dwname"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.dwdob"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.dwpanNo"/>
```

I want to save above data in the format:- `[{a.arr.username:any value,a.arr.userdob:any value,a.arr.userpanNo:any value},{a.arr.empname:any value,a.arr.empdob:any value,a.arr.emppanNo:any value},{a.arr.dwname:any value,a.arr.dwdob:any value,a.arr.dwpanNo:any value}]`.

In my directive:-

```
scope.a.array=[];
    var properties = Object.keys(scope.a.arr);
        for(var i=0;i<properties.length;i++){
            scope.a.array.push({});
            scope.a.array[scope.a.array.length - 1][properties[i]] = scope.a.arr[properties[i]];
         };
```

But above code is creating data like this:- `[{a.arr.username:any value},{a.arr.userdob:any value},{a.arr.userpanNo:any value},{a.arr.empname:any value},{a.arr.empdob:any value},{a.arr.emppanNo:any value},{a.arr.dwname:any value},{a.arr.dwdob:any value},{a.arr.dwpanNo:any value}]`

It is pushing different properties in array instead of combining them. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Is it possible to change `<input type="text" ng-model="a.arr.username"/>` to something like `<input type="text" ng-model="a.arr[0].username"/>` ?

Comment: @Teqchiqe, then it will create array like:- a.arr[0:{},1:{}]. Which is not the format I want.

Comment: But, that looks same as your expected format !

Comment: And just avoid confusion, the result would be `a.arr` would look like `[{},{}]` and not like `[0:{},1:{}]`

Comment: @Teqchiqe, I have already tried like this:- ng-model="a.arr[0].username". The result is:-  [0:{},1:{}]

Comment: That's a bit strange, as `[0:{},1:{}]` does not look a valid expression to me.